# How to find focus on blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have search text box on my web site and when ever user type input value, a new div that called search-result, will be appear. The code is here:

Now I need a code to hide search window when user leave text box except user click on search-result div.

```
$(".searchbox-container").on("blur", "#SearchTextBox", function () {

    var isUserClickedOnSearchDiv=??????//MY QUESTION: How to check user focus on .search-result?
    if (!isUserClickedOnSearchDiv)
    {
        $(".search-result").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: So you want to focus div. isn't it?

Comment: @Jai, In div I have a text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( $('.search-result').is(':focus') ) {

}
```

or

```
if (document.activeElement.className.indexOf('search-result') != -1) {

}
```

as this is checked within a blur event of another element, you probably need a timeout to give the browser time to change to the focused element